# UITableView placeholder for dequeued cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, placeholder

There's this stupid little thing thats annoying me and i'd love to hear your opinion about it.

I'm using a UITableView with custom UITableViewCell's to display some news item from an RSS feed. this is working great ,

the only problem is - when is scroll down, i see the "old" cells, and only when my scroll stops, it loads the new content.

So my question is  - can i somehow put a placeholder so it would at least show "loading" when scrolling or some other kind of indication?

Thanks in advance :)
Shai

Comment: Could you show us your code, especially cellForRowAtIndexPath and the method that your are calling to update your custom cells? Thanks

Comment: Hey Martin, here is it :) Thank you http://pastebin.com/2acWU42Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When do you fill you cells with content, normally you do this in the `UITableViewDataSource`

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This will get called every time a cell is needed before displaying it. If you set the data form that cell here is will be update before it gets displayed.

If you are grabbing something from the web, which could take some time, this is the place to set any content that you grab from the web to loading or placeholder images.

Then in the `UITableViewDelegate`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Start the async fetching of data and update the cell when the data is received.

Comment: The willDisplayCell solution sounds like exactly what i need! ill try that, thank you ! :)

Comment: Hey, I've tried doing the following with no success, any idea what i'm doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/hUGvGt5x

Comment: Your are using a webview in the tableview? the problem is that you don't have enough control over the webview. It will only start loading  we it is make visible.

Comment: I have a web view but the contents are static, i don't load them from a remote url... so I'm not sure whats the problem - The problem in what i sent here is that it doesn't make the activity loader go away for some weird reason

Answer (score -1):

To avoid duplication of previous data in new cell, use an unique CellIdentifier.

```
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row];
    NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {   
        cell = [[ActivitiesCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
```

In NewsCell.m file, use following code and load the new cell by calling **initWithStyle** method, instead of using **loadNibNamed**.

```
    - (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
    {
        self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
        if (self) 
        {
    // Initialization code. 
        }
        return self;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good idea as it would create many cells in the memory instead of re-using a single one which is what i want - i just want a way to put some "loading" on it while it updates the data after scrolling.

Comment: It will be reusing the same cell which will have the same Identifier.

Comment: Yes, but it would still create one identifier for each cell, no ? The point is having one identifier for all cells- i think. My experience with UITableView is quite lacking :)

Comment: Having one identifier for all cells is the reason for your problem, even though if you want to follow your logic, you can use a blank white UILabel on the top of all NewCell subViews to cover and as all controls are to be filled with data, just hide the UILabel.

Comment: Thats more or less what i'm trying to do with no success. Anyways i'll keep messing with it. Thank you anyways.